# Expected 'curr' host dependency tree (in host-dep-tree-curr.txt) error

Tags: stellar-core

I have cloned latest version of stellar core from stellar github. To check how does cargo work for this latest release, just remove the cargo.lock and run cargo build command to generate the cargo.lock file again. After that I build the stellar-core. When I try to generate seed by using sudo ./stellar-core gen-seed command getting below error

```
Expected 'curr' host dependency tree (in host-dep-tree-curr.txt) 
Found 'curr' host dependency tree (in Cargo.lock)
```

Then I copy the found content and paste it into host-dep-tree-curr.txt file and rebuild. After generating the build again I try to generate the seed getting same error as above but this time I have checked Cargo.lock and host-dep-tree-curr.txt both files contents are same. I have checked the stellar doc but got nothing. Any suggestion..